# DependencyResolver - configure with IDependencyResolver or ServiceLocator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a web application that uses `Unity` and `ServiceLocator`. On `App_Start`, I need to configure the `ServiceLocator` and `DependencyResolver`:

```
// container is a Unity container
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

I can either configure `DependencyResolver` as above, or alternatively:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(ServiceLocator.Current);
```

My question is - does it make any difference?

Comment: Why do you need ServiceLocator in this case ?

Comment: I have the following code in one of the libraries I am using, which I didn't author: ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(handlerType); I understand that it is not that typical to use GetInstance, but I'm not sure I want to refactor it because it could take me some time. Thanks!